# Usar un location.href en php con variables de javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

Necesito pasar las variables x, y de javascript a php.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* Posicon relativa del punto en la imagen del mapa*/
    $(".mapa_zona").mousedown(function(event){
        if(event.which == 3){//Solo se cumple la condicion al realizar click derecho
            //Calculamos la posicion relativa donde se ha hecho click derecho
            if(event.offsetX == undefined){ // para firefox
                x = event.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
                y = event.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
            }else{ // chrome
                x = event.offsetX;
                y = event.offsetY;
            }
               localtion.href = " <?php url php con las variables de javascript ?>  "
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: la respuesta no va en la pregunta, por favor colócala justo abajo

Answer (score 2):

Lo que intentas hacer no es posible. Es importante tener claro el modelo cliente-servidor: la llamada al PHP se ejecuta en el servidor y ahí se genera todo el HTML, CSS y JS que se entrega al navegador. Una vez que la página está cargada en el navegador, se ejecuta el código JS.

Una posible solución a lo que quieres hacer sería poner placeholders en el sitio en el que quieres poner X e Y (durante la ejecución de PHP), y luego reemplazar esos placeholders a través de JS.

Por supuesto hay soluciones más elegantes usando otros modelos de programación de frontales, pero en tu caso (PHP + jQuery simple) quizá sea la opción más sencilla sin tener que hacer muchos cambios.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de nada teniendo en cuenta que NO son buenas prácticas de programación y te recomendaría cambiar a MVC en vez de usar este tipo de "ñapas".

En el supuesto que quieras pasar las variables php a través de $_GET en php esta podría ser una posible solución:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
/* Posicon relativa del punto en la imagen del mapa*/
$(".mapa_zona").mousedown(function(event){
    if(event.which == 3){//Solo se cumple la condicion al realizar click derecho
        //Calculamos la posicion relativa donde se ha hecho click derecho
        if(event.offsetX == undefined){ // para firefox
            x = event.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
            y = event.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
        }else{ // chrome
            x = event.offsetX;
            y = event.offsetY;
        }
           localtion.href = "<? echo http://www.servidor.com/archivo.php?x="+x+"&y="+y+"?>"
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Yo usaría GET/POST para pasar las variables. Piensa que estás usando javascript en el lado del cliente y PHP en el lado del servidor. Esto te puede servir de guía https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php